# Marriage and moksha.

Tags: moksha, marriage

In Hinduism, it believes that marriage is a bonding for next 7 lives. Is that mean that he will not attain moksha at least in next 6 lives?

Comment: Hahaha @santanudebnath. If a soul is ready for moksha, no power can hinder it

Comment: The 7 lives bond seems to be a popular movie meme. I don't think it has any scriptural basis in Hinduism.

Comment: Is that so @user1952500? I heard that the 7 rounds around the sacred fire signifies the bonding for 7 lives.

Comment: @SantanuDebnath I have heard of the saptapadi which has scriptural basis, which are 7 steps taken in one direction, and which are followed in South Indian marriages. The 7 whirls around the fire is something unique to North Indian marriages(I think). I do not know the background behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's not true.**
If one remains detached with own spouse & family, even while married, then that person is said to have knowledge & is eligible to attain self realisation.
<sub>BTW, "detached" doesn't mean "avoidance" of family. It should be interpreted as "not much excited".</sub>

> BG 13.10-12 - Non-attachment and **absence of fondness with regard to children, wives, homes, etc.**, and constant equanimity of the mind with regard to the attainment of the desirable and the undesirable; And unwavering devotion to 'Me' with single minded concentration; inclination to repair into a clean place; lack of delight in a crowd of people; Steadfastness in the knowledge of the Self, contemplation on the Goal of the knowledge of Reality --- these are **spoken of as Knowledge**. Ignorance is that which is other than this.

---

Note that in earlier times, polygamy was allowed. If "7 lives bond" was to be true then, the husband will keep taking incarnation after incarnation to finish each wife's 7. Hence it should be considered as a folklore. If it's true, even then marriage itself doesn't stop a person from attaining Moksha. e.g. Sri RAma, Drona, Krishna, ...
<sub>This folklore is mainly popular due to various movie songs. For example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6b2ua56GWo8) it talks about 100 lives!</sub>

Comment: "If "7 lives bond" was to be true then, the husband will keep taking incarnation after incarnation to finish each wife's 7." LOL ! Hahaha!

Comment: That was also on my mind and I thought to pose the question after watching the answers of this question. I agree that the question was silly. Thanks any way.